# Error during inheriting from template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am facing errors when trying to do something similar as described below. Is this possible using class templates in c++.

I want to pass locally declared objects of class B and C and propagate till class A using the D class which acts as common interface for B and C interacting with A.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
Class A
{
 protected:
 T1 _t1;
 T2 _t2;
 public:
 A(T1 t1 , T2 t2) : _t1(t1), _t2(t2) {}
};

class B {// do something};

class C {// do something};

template<typename M, typename N>
class D : public A<M,N>
{
  public:
  D(M m, N n)
  {
     A(m,n);
  }
};

int main()
{
  B objB;
  C objC;

  D<B,C> objD(objB, objC);

  return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: You don't say what kind of errors you get, but one is the `D` constructor that should be `D(M m, N n) : A(m, n) {}`. Your code constructs a temporary `A` inside the constructor, but forgets to initialize the base class.

Comment: Do us the favour and post real code. It's annoying to copy & paste this into an online compiler tool just to find out that you wrote `Class` instead of `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the syntax errors (e.g. `Class` instead of `class` and parenthesis in comments) you should explicitly call the base class' constructor with the arguments you intend to pass to it

```
template<typename M, typename N>
class D : public A<M,N>
{
  public:
  D(M m, N n) : A<M,N>(m,n)
  {}
};
```

since `A` does not have a default constructor.

[Example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d20a440fa82bc0c6)